# React Typescript list mapped table row not rendering

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I have a list of objects called items. I want to each object in the list to a row in the table. However, the rows are not being rendered. I'm using typescript with react-bootstrap. I'm wondering why this happened and how to fix it. Thanks!

Template.tsx

```
export default function Templates() {
    const items = [
        {
          "name": "Item 1",
          "alt": "First",
          "description": "This is the first item"
        },
        {
          "name": "Item 2",
          "alt": "Second",
          "description": "This is the second item"
        },
        {
          "name": "Item 3",
          "alt": "Third",
          "description": "-"
        }
      ]
    return (
        <>
            <MyTable items={items}>MyTable</MyTable>
        </>
    )
}
```

MyTable.tsx

```
import React from 'react'
import { Table, Button } from 'react-bootstrap'

type TableProps = {
    items: {
        name: string,
        alt: string,
        description: string
    }[]
}
const MyTable: React.FunctionComponent<TableProps> = ({
    items
  }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <Table striped bordered hover variant="dark">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Alt</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {items.map(item => {
                        <tr>
                            <td>{item.name}</td>
                            <td>{item.alt}</td>
                            <td>{item.description}</td>
                        </tr>
                    })}
                </tbody>
            </Table>
        </>
        )
  };

export default MyTable;
```

Right now only the thead are being rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are maping over the items and the map callback return undefined(no return statment),make sure to return the iterated item:

```js
     {items.map(item => {
          return (
            <tr key={item.name}>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.alt}</td>
              <td>{item.description}</td>
            </tr>
          )
        })}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you do not return anything here:

```
{items.map(item => {
    <tr>
       <td>{item.name}</td>
       <td>{item.alt}</td>
       <td>{item.description}</td>
     </tr>
})}
```

In order for it to render something - you have to return.

Try this:

```
{items.map(item => <tr>
  <td>{item.name}</td>
  <td>{item.alt}</td>
  <td>{item.description}</td>
</tr>)}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with how you are using the arrow function inside `items.map`.

Note that there is a difference between the following:

- `item => { <tr></tr> }`: this is a function with statement of `<tr/><tr>` defined in a block with no return statement.
- `item => (<tr></tr>)`: this is function which returns a single expression `(<tr></tr>)`
- `item => { return (<tr></tr>)}`: this is a function with statement in a block with a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Since others have already answered, we can simplify it by replacing the curly braces and the return statement with parenthesis around the JSX you want to return

Ex:

```js
     {items.map(item => (
            <tr key={item.name}>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.alt}</td>
              <td>{item.description}</td>
            </tr>
          )
        )}
```

edit: what Soc said ^